# how to extract a headline form a url?

Tags: python, regex, string, url-parameters, urlparse

I have a dataset of headlines, such as

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/lifestyle/tech/this-is-a-very-nice-headline-my-friend/2013/04/26/acjhrjk-2e1-1krjke4-9el8c-2eheje_story.html?tid=sm_fb

http://www.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/15/sports/baseball/another-very-nice.html?smid=tw-somedia&seid=auto

http://worldnews.stack.com/news/2013/07/22/54216-hello-another-one-here?lite

http://www.stack.com/article_email/hello-one-here-that-is-cool-1545545554-lMyQjAxMTAHFJELMDgxWj

http://www.stack.com/2013/11/13/tech/tricky-one/the-real-one/index.html

http://www.stack.com/2013/11/13/tech/the-good-one.html

http://www.stack.com/news/science-and-technology/54512-hello-world-here-is-a-weird-character#b02g07f20b14
```

I need to extract from these kind of links the proper headline, that is:

- this-is-a-very-nice-headline-my-friend
- another-very-nice
- hello-another-one-here
- hello-one-here-that-is-cool
- the-real-one
- the-good-one
- hello-world-here-is-a-weird-character

so the rule seems to find the **longest** string of the form `word1-word2-word3`- that has a `/` at the right or left border and **without** considering

1. words with more than 3 digits (for instance `acjhrjk-2e1-1krjke4-9el8c-2eheje` in the first link, or `54216` in the third one ,
2. excluding stuff like `.html`.

How can I do that using **regex** in Python? I believe regex is the only viable solution here unfortunately. Packages such as `yurl` or `urlparse` can capture the path of the url, but then I am back to using regex to get the headline..

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, regular expressions might not be your best bet.
However, with the specifications you came up with, you could do the following:

```
import re

urls = ['http://www.stackoverflow.com/lifestyle/tech/this-is-a-very-nice-headline-my-friend/2013/04/26/acjhrjk-2e1-1krjke4-9el8c-2eheje_story.html?tid=sm_fb',
'http://www.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/15/sports/baseball/another-very-nice.html?smid=tw-somedia&seid=auto',
'http://worldnews.stack.com/news/2013/07/22/54216-hello-another-one-here?lite',
'http://www.stack.com/article_email/hello-one-here-that-is-cool-1545545554-lMyQjAxMTAHFJELMDgxWj',
'http://www.stack.com/2013/11/13/tech/tricky-one/the-real-one/index.html',
'http://www.stack.com/2013/11/13/tech/the-good-one.html',
'http://www.stack.com/news/science-and-technology/54512-hello-world-here-is-a-weird-character#b02g07f20b14']

regex = re.compile(r'(?<=/)([-\w]+)(?=[.?/#]|$)')
digits = re.compile(r'-?\d{3,}-?')

for url in urls:
    substrings = regex.findall(url)
    longest = max(substrings, key=len)
    headline = re.sub(digits, '', longest)
    print headline
```

---

This will print

```
 this-is-a-very-nice-headline-my-friend
 another-very-nice
 hello-another-one-here
 hello-one-here-that-is-coollMyQjAxMTAHFJELMDgxWj
 the-real-one
 the-good-one
 hello-world-here-is-a-weird-character
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/9eHKQt).

---

#### Explanation

Here, the regex uses **lookarounds** to look for a `/` behind and one of `.?/#` ahead. Any word character and dash in between is captured.
This is not very specific but if you're looking for the longest substring and eliminate more then three consecutive digits afterwards, it might be a good starting point.
As already said in the comments, you might perhaps be better off using linguistic tools.

Comment: thanks!! so it does not capture the second headline?

Comment: also, why are you saying that regex might not be my best bet?

Comment: like nltk for instance?

Comment: @Noobie: yup. But never used it before. Probably a combination of both of them. To give a better answer, provide more URLs.

Comment: thanks again for your great answer! It seems your regex fails for the fourth and the last one however... do you see any solution? for instance I get `science-and-technology` for the last one. Recall that you can have a `slash` on the left **OR** a `slash` on the right, not necessarily both

Comment: thats really great!! can you just explain what `.?/#` means? it looks for zero or more slashes?

Comment: @Noobie: Nope: it looks for one of them (it is a character class after all).